# Loop inserting hyperlinks with If-condition

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, hyperlink

I basically try to put a hyperlink to a cell in Sheet1 linking it to Sheet2 if the text matches "92/65/EEC". I don't understand where I went wrong here. 
Could you please help?

```
Sub Legislation()

 ' Define
 Dim lrow As Long, rng As Range, cell As Range
 lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

' Set the range where to apply the code
Set rng = Range("J5:J" & lrow)

' Define what to look for
 For Each cell In rng
 If InStr(1, cell.Value, "92/65/EEC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
 With cell.Validation
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'List of EU legislation '!A8", TextToDisplay:="92/65/EEC"
    End With
 End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
Anchor:=cell
```

Now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

```
For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "92/65/EEC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'List of EU legislation '!A8", TextToDisplay:="92/65/EEC"
    End If
Next cell
```